# Proving the existence of MLE for logistic distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

> Let $X_{1},\cdots,X_{n}\overset{IID}{\sim}\operatorname{Logis}(\theta,\sigma),\theta\in\mathbb{R},\sigma>0$. Prove that there exists an MLE of $\eta = (\theta,\sigma)^T$.

I want to prove this by the following theorem:

For the log-likelihood function $l(\theta)$ whose second partial derivatives are all continous, if the Hessian matrix is negative-definite and limiting $\theta$ to the boundary of the parameter space makes $l(\theta)$ go to negative infinity, there exists a unique solution to $\dot{l}(\theta) = 0$, which is the MLE of $\theta$.

Since the pdf for Logistic distribution is
$$f(x;\theta,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{e^{-\frac{x-\theta}{\sigma}}}{(1+e^{-\frac{x-\theta}{\sigma}})^2}$$
, the log-likelihood function is
$$l(\theta,\sigma) = -n\log{\sigma} -n\frac{\bar{x}-\theta}{\sigma} -2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\log{(1+e^{-\frac{x_{i}-\theta}{\sigma}})}}       $$
and the Hessian matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta^2} & \frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta \partial\sigma} \\
\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \sigma \partial\theta} & \frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \sigma^2}
\end{pmatrix}$ where
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta^2}=-\frac{2}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{-\frac{x_i-\theta}{\sigma}}}{\left(1+e^{-\frac{x_i-\theta}{\sigma}}\right)^2} \\
&\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta \partial \sigma} =\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \sigma \partial \theta} =-\frac{n}{\sigma^2}+\frac{2}{\sigma^3} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{-\frac{x_i-\theta}{\sigma}}\left(\sigma\left(1+e^{-\frac{x_i-\theta}{\sigma}}\right)-\left(x_i-\theta\right)\right)}{\left(1+e^{-\frac{x_i-\theta}{\sigma}}\right)^2} \\
&\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \sigma^2} =\frac{n}{\sigma^2}-\frac{2}{\sigma^3} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i+\frac{2 n \theta}{\sigma^3}+\frac{2}{\sigma^4} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{-\frac{x_i-\theta}{\sigma}}\left(x_i-\theta\right)\left(2 \sigma\left(1+e^{-\frac{x_i-\theta}{\sigma}}\right)-\left(x_i-\theta\right)\right)}{\left(1+e^{-\frac{x_i-\theta}{\sigma}}\right)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
I could show that $\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \infty}{l(\theta,\sigma^*)}=\lim_{\theta \rightarrow -\infty}{l(\theta,\sigma^*)}=\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0+}{l(\theta^*,\sigma)}=\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow \infty}{l(\theta^*,\sigma)}=-\infty$ somehow, but I don't know how to show that the hessian matrix is negative-definite.

Comment: I would treat $\frac1{\sigma}$ as a constant. It neither affects the x-value uf the mle, nor if it is a maximum or a minimum.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I can't get the context of treating $1/\sigma$ as a constant when the objective is to prove that there exists an MLE of $\sigma$.